# I cannot rewrite Mockito unit test to Spock Specification

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, mockito, spock

I have an implementation of Spring interface `UserDetailsService`:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        final UserEntity user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Cannot find user with username " + username);
        }

        return new User(user);
    }
}
```

`UserRepository` is a standard interface extendng `JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long>` where `UserEntity` is my model class.

`User` is an implementation of `UserDetails` from Spring Framework.

And I wrote an unit test for this method using JUnit and Mockito. These tests are working:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class UserDetailsServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Test
    public void shouldFindUser() throws Exception {
        // given
        final UserEntity user = new UserEntity(
                1L,
                "username",
                "username@email.com",
                "password",
                new ArrayList<>() // list of roles
        );

        when(UserDetailsServiceTestContext.userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()))
                .thenReturn(user);

        // when
        final UserDetails result = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(user.getUsername());

        // then
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo(UserFactory.create(user));
        verify(UserDetailsServiceTestContext.userRepository)
                .findByUsername(user.getUsername());
    }

    @Test(expected = UsernameNotFoundException.class)
    public void shouldNotFindUser() throws Exception {
        // given
        when(UserDetailsServiceTestContext.userRepository.findByUsername(anyString()))
                .thenReturn(null);

        // when
        final UserDetails result = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(new String());
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    static class UserDetailsServiceTestContext {

        @MockBean
        private static UserRepository userRepository;

        @Bean
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return new UserDetailsServiceImpl(userRepository);
        }
    }

}
```

And now I try to write these tests using Groovy and Spock framework. I wrote the following specification:

```
def 'should find user'() {
        given:
            def user = new UserEntity(
                1L,
                "username",
                "username@email.com",
                "password"
                new ArrayList<>() // list of roles
            )

            userRepository.findByUsername(user.username) >> user
            // userRepository.findByUsername(_ as String) >> user // also working

        when:
            def result = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(user.username)

        then:
            result == new User(user)
    }
```

and this test is working. But when I want verify calling of userRepository by add in section `then:` a statement `1 * userRepository.findByUsername(user.username)` or `1 * userRepository.findByUsername(_ as String)` I get an error `UserDetailsServiceSpec.should find user and return new User:36 » UsernameNotFound`. line 36 is in section `when:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the stubbing and verification in one step

```
then:
1 * userRepository.findByUsername(user.username) >> user
```

For details here is my answer from [Predefined mock response in Spock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360750/predefined-mock-response-in-spock):

Please refer to the [documentation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing)

> When mocking and stubbing the same method call, they have to happen in the same interaction. In particular, the following Mockito-style splitting of stubbing and mocking into two separate statements will not work:

```
setup:
subscriber.receive("message1") >> "ok"

when:
publisher.send("message1")

then:
1 * subscriber.receive("message1")
```

> As explained in Where to Declare Interactions, the receive call will first get matched against the interaction in the then: block. Since that interaction doesn’t specify a response, the default value for the method’s return type (null in this case) will be returned. (This is just another facet of Spock’s lenient approach to mocking.). Hence, the interaction in the setup: block will never get a chance to match.

---

When dealing with spring and transaction proxies you might also run into this problem https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/758